# Scheme tail-recursion/iteration

Tags: recursion, scheme, iteration, racket, tail-recursion

I've built a recursive function in scheme, which will repeat a given function f, n times on some input.

```
(define (recursive-repeated f n)
  (cond ((zero? n) identity)
        ((= n 1) f)
        (else (compose f (recursive-repeated f (- n 1))))))
```

I need to build an iterative version of this function with tail recursion, which I think I've done right if I understand tail recursion correctly.

```
(define (iter-repeated f n)
  (define (iter count total)
    (if (= count 0)
        total
        (iter (- count 1) (compose f total))))
  (iter n identity))
```

My question is, is this actually iterative? I believe I have it built correctly using tail recursion, but it's still technically deferring a bunch of operations until count = 0, where it executes however many compositions it's stacked up.

Comment: Why would it "deferring a bunch of operations until n = 0"? At `count = 0`, you only return `total`, which is perhaps the most simple work with virtually no cost at all.

Comment: Right, but I guess what I'm saying is, when you return total, it's returning a stack of operations like

    `(compose square (compose square (compose square (identity x))))`

which it evaluates when total is returned as opposed to when the tail call happens. Or am I just overthinking this way too much?

Comment: @EddieV All arguments to a function are evaluated before the function is called.

Comment: I see. Well I guess that makes sense then, thanks!

Comment: While it is iterative, what you end up returning is a big gnarly nest of lambdas. Noamik's answer below give you a way to do it without the mess.

Answer (score 3):

You pose a good question. You went from a recursive process (`recursive-repeated`) which builds a recursive process (`(f (f (f ...)))`) to an iterative process (`iter-repeated`) that builds the same recursive process.

You're right in thinking that you've basically done the same thing because the end result is the same. You just constructed the same chain in two different ways. This is the "consequence" of using `compose` in your implementation.

Consider this approach

```
(define (repeat n f)
  (λ (x)
    (define (iter n x)
      (if (zero? n)
          x
          (iter (- n 1) (f x))))
    (iter n x)))
```

Here, instead of building up an entire chain of function calls ahead of time, we'll return a single lambda that waits for the input argument. When the input argument is specified, we will loop inside the lambda in an iterative way for `n` times.

Let's see it work

```
(define (add1 x) (+ x 1))

;; apply add1 5 times to 3
(print ((repeat 5 add1) 3)) ;; → 8
```